# PHP mktime suddenly in the past?

Tags: php, mktime

I have a script containing this line:

```
$showdate = mktime(18, 59, 0, 08, 02, 2015);
```

That should set the variable to 1438556340 (with a date of August 2, 2015 at 6:59pm)

BUT, for some insane reason, as of this morning, it's setting the variable to 1417564740 (December 02, 2014).

Nothing has changed as far as the script goes in weeks. So why the sudden change? And is there any way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Change 08 to 8 and see if it makes a difference? It might handle octals in some different way of the server has had something done to it.

Comment: maybe there's a time issue on your server, mkTime depends on server's current time. check if the date and time on your server is ok

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen, you are a genius! That fixed it! But that still begs the question why the sudden change?

Comment: I don't see how it would ever have worked as-is, @Charles. PHP has always had the "leading-zero-means octal" insanity, inherited from C.  (Only it makes it even more insane by not triggering any sort of error condition by default, just silently interpreting it as 0.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami Kuhmonen points out in the first comment to the question you shouldn't use 08 ([invalid octal literal](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)) when you mean 8 (decimal).

```
<?php
echo mktime(18, 59, 0, 08, 02, 2015), "\r\n";
echo mktime(18, 59, 0, 8, 2, 2015), "\r\n";

echo 8, "\r\n";
echo 08, "\r\n";
```

prints

```
1417543140
1438534740
8
0
```

Answer (score 0):

08 is parsed as an octal number

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero).

08 doesnt eist in  octal so returns 0

> octal       : 0[0-7]+

mktime has the following in the docs

> month The number of the month relative to the end of the previous
>   year. Values 1 to 12 reference the normal calendar months of the year
>   in question. Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference
>   the months in the previous year in reverse order, so 0 is December, -1
>   is November, etc. Values greater than 12 reference the appropriate
>   month in the following year(s).

so its getting December of last year

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php